# DynamoDBVersion Attribute with Conditional Update

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using the [.NET object persistence model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html) with DynamoDB, and am making use of the built in [optimistic locking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.VersionSupport.html) using the `DynamoDBVersion` attribute.

```
[DynamoDBTable("items")]
public class MyItem
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBVersion]
    public int? Version { get; set; }
}
```

The save operation 
using `DynamoDBContext` is simple.

```
await _dbContext.SaveAsync(item);
```

Recently I added a custom update condition, changing the save operation to the following.

```
var table = _dbContext.GetTargetTable<MyItem>();
await table.UpdateItemAsync(_dbContext.ToDocument(item), new UpdateItemOperationConfig
{
    ConditionalExpression = ...
});
```

This appears to have broken the built in optimistic locking, and none of the items in the table contain a `Version` property. Is there any way to use the attribute along with a conditional write, or somehow manually implement optimistic locking using the low level .NET SDK?

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting to put in the ConditionalExpression? You must have the object client-side else optimistic locking will prevent the update from occurring anyway. So you should be able to do any conditional checks client side?

Just be clear, you have to load an object before you can save it with optimistic locking. Are you loading the object first?

Comment: I don't think the object has to be loaded first - in these cases `Version` is `null` when saving, and Dynamo increments the value in the table. Some of my updates are read-update-write and some are just write. The condition applies to all operations, but optimistic locking is required for read-update-write cases.

Comment: I still don't understand. Either you load the item, do your checks client side and update the item. In this case you don't need a conditional operator because optimistic locking stops you updating the wrong item. Or you force a save without loading first, in which case you overwrite any existing item, so you don't need a conditional expression. Can you describe what your conditions are?

Comment: Sure! Multiple handlers process events with sequence numbers and update a read-model. Events must be applied to the read-model in order. Each item contains the sequence number of the latest event to update it. The condition ensures that any update increments the sequence number by exactly 1. This condition alone doesn't guarantee that another handler hasn't updated an item during a read-update-write. I can actually work around this by checking the sequence number both on the client after a read and then again in the DB on write, but would rather use built in optimistic locking if possible.

Comment: Ah ok. You should just able to do the check client side only. So you have an event to process, you load the read-model, check the event sequence number is OK - lets say it is - then save the read-model. You don't need an update condition because you KNOW the persisted read-model is the same as your client side object (else the save will fail). Then you have another event to process, load the read-model, the event is not in sequence so don't try and save. You get another event to process, load the model, sequence is OK, save, the DB model has been changed by another handler so the save fails.

Comment: Yep that would work fine, but it would mean I'd have to do a read every time I want to update an item. A conditional update that happens in the DB means I can avoid a read for the majority of events. There are certainly ways of achieving what I am after without using the optimistic locking feature - my question however is _can I use optimistic locking along with a conditional update_ so I don't have to add extra logic to my client code. I suspect the answer is no.